# Pthread arguments

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am having problems with passing arguments to new threads, I have the following

```
 doRowOffset[0] = 0;
 for(threads = 1; threads < NUMTHREADS; threads++){
      doRowOffset[threads] = threads;
      printf("Do row: %d\n", doRowOffset[threads]);
      pthread_create(&threadHandler[threads], NULL, multiplyRows, (void *) &doRowOffset[threads]);
 }
```

and

```
void * multiplyRows(void * dealWithRows){
        int offset = *((int *) dealWithRows);
        printf("%d\n", *((int *) dealWithRows));
        printf("Offset: %d\n", offset);
        printf("Size: %d\n", partitionSize/NUMTHREADS);
        printf("Calculated Offset: %d\n", offset*partitionSize/NUMTHREADS);
        ...
```

Now I expect to see the following output

Do row: 1
1
Offset: 1
Size: 2
Calculated offset: 2

However I keep getting garbage values or 0 for dealWithRows when I get into the thread am I doing something wrong with argument passing?

Comment: would you please post the definition of doRowOffset? I asume it's an `int`, but better to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the address of a variable that is changing, you have to expect that it may change on you :-)

What's probably happening is that you're setting `doRowOffset` to 1 (for example) then starting the thread. Before that thread kicks up and dereferences its pointer, you change `doRowOffset` for the next thread.

Then when the first thread finally dereferences the address, you've changed the underlying value.

There are two ways to handle this. The first is to synchronise the main thread and child thread so that the main one waits until the child had dereferenced the variable and stored the value locally. Only then does the main thread change the variable for the next thread it's about to start. However, that sort of defeats the purpose of threads :-)

The other is to cast the actual integer value (not the address) to a void pointer, which is passed to the thread function. This will mean the value will be copied to the stack of the thread function rather than the address, and the main thread will then not be able to affect it.

Something like:

```
pthread_create (&threadHandler[threads], NULL, multiplyRows,
    (void *) doRowOffset); // <<-- Note, removed the '&'.
```

in the main thread and:

```
int offset = (int) dealWithRows;
```

in the child thread.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense, I guess I got into the thinking that the value was buffered but now that I look at it I should have known otherwise since its passing a pointer... Thanks

Comment: @legion, yes, the parameter actually _is_ buffered (on the stack) but, since it's a pointer to data that _isn't_ buffered, that doesn’t help :-)

Comment: I am still having problems I have edited my original post with what I have now, I changed it to an array which should mean that these aren't changing anymore

Comment: @legion, if you changed it into an array then you haven't done what I suggested to fix it, in which case you should probably ask a _new_ question since its nature has changed. If you tried what I _suggested_ and it didn't work, I'll be happy to help out further. One thing you _may_ want to check is that `doRowOffset` isn't going out of scope (such as if you started the threads from a function, then exited the function).

Comment: Ya that was it I was about to retract my comment I guess I had commented out the pthread_join for some reason and the array was getting kicked off the stack. Thanks for the help though I will keep your way in mind as well

Comment: By the way, `(void *)(intptr_t)val` and `(int)(intptr_t)arg` can be useful cast idioms to avoid annoying compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

If `doRowOffset` is an `int`, you shouldn't see *garbage*, unless the thread creating *function* finishes and you allocated the variable on the stack and it gets overwritten.

But note that there is only one variable, and you are passing its address, so when the thread starts it could see an updated value.

Pass the actual value:

```
pthread_create(&threadHandler[threads], NULL, multiplyRows, (void *) threads);

void * multiplyRows(void * dealWithRows){
    int offset = (int) dealWithRows);
}
```